# how to get data from Child JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, weather-api

I am making a weather app and I am trying to get the date and weather from my son file. I successfully get inside "daily" but I can't get inside "data" which is inside "daily". this is the code:

```
func downloadForecastWeather(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
    Alamofire.request(FORECAST_API_URL).responseJSON { (response) in
        let result = response.result
        if let dictionary = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let list = dictionary["list"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                for item in list {
                    let forecast = ForecastWeather(weatherDict: item)
                    self.forecastArray.append(forecast)
                }
                self.forecastArray.remove(at: 0)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        completed()
    }
}
```

and here is my ForecastWeather class:

```
init(weatherDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    if let temp = weatherDict["temperatureMin"] as? Double {

            let rawValue = (temp - 273.15).rounded(toPlaces: 0)
            self._temp = rawValue
        }


    if let date = weatherDict["time"] as? Double {

        let rawDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium

        self._date = "\(rawDate.dayOfTheWeek())"
    }

}
```

Here is a link for json:
https://api.darksky.net/forecast/132d3013b6e07bdf66159c1f5a90f76c/37.8267,-122.4233
So basically my question is how to get data from "data" which is inside "daily" and use it in my for in method.

Comment: Cast your response to JSON using JSON.parse(response) instead of using a Dictionary. In this way you will have a JavaScript object ready to use. Try on your browser console.

Comment: Use codable don't use dictionary now https://app.quicktype.io?share=xDUSroTxa34fuGQWdv9j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using with `SwiftyJSON` it is easy to integrate in your code, all you have to do is to add below code inside your `downloadForecastWeather` function.

```
func downloadForecastWeather(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
        Alamofire.request(FORECAST_API_URL).responseJSON { (response) in

            let jsondata = JSON(response.result.value!)

            if let myData = jsondata["list"]["daily"]["data"].arrayObject { // here you can access your data inside daily
                for data in myData {
                    let forecast = ForecastWeather(weatherDict: data)
                    self.forecastArray.append(forecast)
                }
                self.forecastArray.remove(at: 0)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            completed()
        }
    }
```

For more details please refer to this [Documentation](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

I hope it works for you.

: D

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swift 4, you should be able to adopt the Codable protocol with your ForecastWeather model.

This would allow you to do something a little bit like this (not exactly like this):

```
let weather = try JSONDecoder().decode(Weather.self, from: jsonData!)
```

For a reasonably in depth read, I recommend starting here in the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

If you want more reading, I found this book (paid) to be fantastic. 
[Flight School Guide to Swift Codable](https://flight.school/books/codable)

Comment: “with your ForecastWeather class”? Rather use struct for this... or it depends, so maybe “with your ForecastWeather model”?

Comment: Good call :) Changed